# inverted comma and string in python

Tags: python, string, literals

I'm kinda' new to python, but I have already written many programs including some like download-managers, games and text-editors which require a lot of string manipulation.
For representing a string literal I use either single or double inverted commas.. whichever comes to my mind first at that time.

Although I haven't yet faced any trouble. My question: is there any purpose for which python allows both or is it just for compatibility, usability etc?

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python/56190#56190) will give you some tips on when to use which.

Comment: Never heard quote marks called inverted commas before. Details are here: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals These details are different for python 3

Comment: OK, that's why the results in the searches were so weird. This is a repeat then. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between `"string"` and `'string'` in Python, so, as you suggest, it's just for usability.

```
>>> 'string' == "string"
True
```

You can also use triple quotes for multiline strings:

```
>>> mystring = """Hello
... World!"""
>>> mystring
'Hello\nWorld!'
```

Another trick is that adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated:

```
>>> mystring = "Hello" 'World!'
>>> mystring
'HelloWorld!'
```

There are also [string prefixes which you can read about in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings).

Answer (score 4):

It means you can easily have a string with **either** single or double quotes in it without needing any escape characters.  So you can do:

```
a = 'The knights who say "ni!"'
b = "We're knights of the Round Table, we dance whene'er we're able."
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for compatibility and usability.

It is sometimes useful when you have one of them embedded in the string, so I would use `"Who's there?"` compared to `'He says: "Hello"'`.

The other option is of course triple quoted strings, like

```
"""This is a long string that can contain single quotations like ' or ".
It can also span multiple lines"""
```

which is equal to

```
'''This is a long string that can contain single quotations like ' or ".
It can also span multiple lines'''
```