# Multiline string containing """ (triple quotes)

Tags: python, string-literals

How can I define python multi line string containing """ (3 double quotes)

my desired output is

```
"""
TEST
"""
```

Reason: I am writing a script to create some boilerplate code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783097/when-to-use-triple-single-quotes-instead-of-triple-double-quotes

Answer (score 8):

Use triple single quotes:

```
'''
"""Test"""
'''
```

Comment: Does that mean I can choose my delimiter like bash HERE DOC ?

Comment: @forvaidya No. You can use *either* `"""` or `'''`.

Comment: No. Only `'''` and `"""` are valid. (See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)

Comment: @forvaidya: You can use either single quotes or double quotes, and you can use one of them or three of them.  So your options are `'`, `"`, `'''`, or `"""`.  That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try,

```
>>> a = "\"\"\"TEST\"\"\""
>>> print a
"""TEST"""
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `'''` should work, but just for the case you need *both* of them in a string, you can predefine a string with one of them, such as

```
TRIPSING = "'''"
TRIPDOUB = '"""'
```

and then

```
MYSTRING = TRIPDOUB + "\nTEST\n" + TRIPDOUB
```