# python string good practise: ' vs "

Tags: python, string, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

I have seen that when i have to work with string in Python both of the following sintax are accepted:

```
mystring1  = "here is my string 1"
mystring2  = 'here is my string 2'
```

Is anyway there any difference?

Is it by any reason better use one solution rather than the other?

Cheers,

Comment: What do you guys think is the most popular way?

Comment: The one that gets the job done. :) When you need to encase single quotes, double quote it, and vice-versa. For day-to-day usage, use the one you prefer.

Comment: I tend to use `'` as it requires hitting only one key instead of two

Comment: Definitly a duplicate. Come on man, you didn't even use the search function right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't. When the string contains a single quote, it's easier to enclose it in double quotes, and vice versa. Other than this, my advice would be to pick a style and stick to it.

Another useful type of string literals are triple-quoted strings that can span multiple lines:

```
s = """string literal...
...continues on second line...
...and ends here"""
```

Again, it's up to you whether to use single or double quotes for this.

Lastly, I'd like to mention "raw string literals". These are enclosed in `r"..."` or `r'...'` and prevent escape sequences (such as `\n`) from being parsed as such. Among other things, raw string literals are very handy for specifying regular expressions.

Read more about Python string literals [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: One confusion about raw strings is that people sometimes think they are a special kind of string. They aren't, the leading 'r' just tells the interpreter to do a different kind of processing for the literal that follows, treating backslashes just like ordinary characters. The result is a plain old ordinary string. The "raw" part is the literal, not the result. So I always use the term "raw string literals", I think this focuses the rawness on the literal, not on the string that you get back.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that there is no difference between one and the other, I encountered a lot of the following behavior in the opensource community:

- `"` for text that is supposed to be read (email, feeback, execption, etc)
- `'` for data text (key dict, function arguments, etc)
- triple `"` for any docstring or text that includes `"` and `'`

Comment: I use `'''` all the time for docstrings, since they require one keystroke less to type. I hope that doesn't make my projects any less serious :)

Comment: There is no reason not to. I just never saw it. But it's only less keystrokes on the QWERTY keyboard, not every keyboards in the world. On my keyboard, '"' is easier to use.

Comment: Lol. I just grepped the Python source code. It's full of `'''`. Ok, I guess I have to remove that assertion :-p

Comment: +1 for the idea of using `'` and `"` based on destination, not to say that it's really useful, but I like the concept and will see what I can do with it :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. A matter of style only. Just be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to using `"` simply because that's what most other programming languages use.

So, habit, really.

Comment: And I prefer `'` because in my keyboard it doesn't need the Shift key, while `"` needs. It is really a matter of habit!

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference.

What's better is arguable. I use `"..."` for text strings and `'...'` for characters, because that's consistent with other languages and may save you some keypresses when porting to/from different language. For regexps and SQL queries, I always use `r'''...'''`, because they frequently end up containing backslashes and both types of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Python is all about the least amount of code to get the most effect. The shorter the better. And `'` is, in a way, one dot shorter than `"` which is why I prefer it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone's pointed out, they're functionally identical. However, [PEP 257 (Docstring Conventions)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) suggests always using `"""` around docstrings just for the purposes of consistency. No one's likely to yell at you or think poorly of you if you don't, but there it is.