# String creation: Differences between two syntaxes ' ' and " "?

Tags: python, string, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

Usually we represent , create strings like this

```
 s = 'abc'
```

and also like this

```
 c = "abc"
```

Ideally both ways are same , than why we have two syntax to do the same ? Is there any difference between these two or Ideally they are same.

Comment: Don't forget the third syntax `"""hello there!"""` or `'''this too!'''`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The are essentially the same, except for what you have to escape:

```
"'"
'"'
```

both work, but to incorporate multiple quote types you *must* escape the ones used to create the string:

```
"\"'"
'"\''
```

The two exist to make it easy for you to avoid having to escape your quotes, so the following two are easy:

```
'She said: "Not so fast!"'
"Won't you come with us?"
```

Note that there are also tripple-quote variants:

```
"""Now I can use either quote with more freedom: ' and "."""
'''Now I can use either quote with more freedom: ' and ".'''
```

These also allow newlines to be included without escaping:

```
"""A
multiline
string
is
easy.
"""
```

That last example would require you to use excessive `\n` escape sequences otherwise.

Comment: The question will probably be closed as a duplicate. But I consider your answer better than the ones existing on that question. Could you maybe copy your answer to that question?

Comment: @mizipzor: Note that closing is not the same as deletion; my answer will still be available. You can flag the question for merging if you feel strongly about it, that'll preserve my answer with votes too. Use the `Other` option and explain your reasoning.