# Why does python use both " " and ' ' to make a string literal

Tags: python, string, syntax

[Python's Philosophy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonPhilosophy):

```
....
Simple is better than complex. 
....
```

So why does it use both double quote `" "` and single quote `' '` to indicate something is a string literal.

I was lost when I typed:

```
x = "aa"
x
```

And saw:

```
'aa'
```

But not:

```
"aa"
```

When I saw the above philosophy, I doubted it. It needs some explanations.

Comment: The most relevant part of the philosophy is "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.", not "simple vs complex" which is completely unrelated. Anyway, I believe that Guido decided to use both `"` and `'`, since a lot of languages use `'` for characters and `"` for strings, but in python characters a length-one strings, hence people used to denote characters with `'` can do that in python.

Comment: @Bakuriu *Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules* ;)

Answer (score 16):

This isn't complex at all. In fact, it's rather helpful.

Both `''` and `""` can be used in python. [There's no difference, it's up to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

In your example, when you type `x`, you are given the representation of the string (i.e, it's equivalent to `print repr(x)`). It wouldn't have mattered if you did `x = 'aa'`

I like to use either for cases such as:

```
print 'Bill said, "Hey!"'
print "I'm coming!"
```

If we used `"` for the first example, then there would be an error because Python would interpret it as `"Bill said, "`.

If we used `'` for the second example, then there would be an error because Python would interpret it as `'I'`

Of course, you could just escape the apostrophes, but *beautiful is better than ugly*.

Comment: In short, having both is less complex than having to escape quotes all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "" to be able to write "I'm legend" for example.