# Python - difference between 'a' and "a"?

Tags: python

I have been always mixing these two notations, regarding them both as a string in Python.

What are the differences between them?

Under what circumstances can we only use one of them?

Comment: There is no difference, they are completely interchangeable.

Comment: Also check the relevant [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: Use single quotes. You'll need less ink if you're going to print the code. :-)

Comment: I use single quotes because it's less work for my pinky to not have to hit the shift key.

Answer (score 2):

They're the same. The only time it ever matters is that you have to escape the delimiter character: `"\""` vs `'"'`.

Personally, I usually use `'` for strings that aren't "user-visible" and `"` for strings that are, but I'm not completely consistent with that and I don't think it's common practice.

Comment: I'm really bad at this.  I have source files with mixed quotes all over the place...  I've recently started working with a linter which complains every time I'm inconsistent in my quoting and it's always complaining at me ...

Answer (score 2):

No difference at all:  they mean exactly the same thing.  Yes, that's unusual for Python ;-)

Some programmers like to put one-character strings in single quotes, and longer strings in double quotes.  Probably a habit carried over from C.  Do what you like :-)

Ah:  a [lot more discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python).

Comment: If you're a fan of programming psychology, here's an oddity I noticed years ago:  triple-quoted strings in Python are, at least 10 to 1, spelled with double quotes instead of single quotes.  Something about the way our brains are wired ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They are equal and depend on your preferences

but you can do this:

```
>>> print 'Double" quote inside single'
Double" quote inside single
>>> print "Single' quote inside double"
Single' quote inside double
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, though I prefer to use `'single quotes'`as they're easier to read