# mysqldb error in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to insert a value into my local MySQL instance using Python but I keep getting an error

Here is my code:

```
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'testDB')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO testDB.testPython VALUES (%s)''',("HelloWorld"))
con.commit()
```

but I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TypeError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) is a basic Python error:

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.

Your trouble is you forgot to place a comma in your tuple, and without it is considered as the object in parenthesis: your single string.

Explanation with interpreter:

```
In [1]: ('Hello')
Out[1]: 'Hello'
In [2]: ('Hello',)
Out[2]: ('Hello',)
```

Fix like this to resolve your trouble :

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO testDB.testPython VALUES (%s)', ("HelloWorld",))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the triple quotes, this will treat your sql includ the parameter as a string literal. Use the standard quote ( " ) instead.

Comment: He make as in MySQLdb doc: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

Comment: But... standard quotes make string literals as well.

Comment: Maybe I make a mistake, but there is no difference between simple and double quote in Python: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python