# A simple python confusion about format string

Tags: python

New to python and I am learning this tutorial:
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex8.html

I just cannot see why the line "But it didn't sing." got printed out with double-quote and all the others got printed with single quote.. Cannot see any difference from the code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes depends on the string: if there are no quotes, it will use simple quotes:

```
>>> """no quotes"""
'no quotes'
```

if there is a single quote, it will use double quotes:

```
>>> """single quote:'"""
"single quote:'"
```

if there is a double quote, it will use single quotes:

> > > """double quote:" """
> > >           'double quote:" '

if there are both, it will use single quotes, hence escaping the single one:

```
>>> """mix quotes:'" """
'mix quotes:\'" '
>>> """mix quotes:"' """
'mix quotes:"\' '
>>> '''mix quotes:"' '''
'mix quotes:"\' '
```

There won't be a difference though when you print the string:

```
>>> print '''mix quotes:"' '''
mix quotes:"'
```

the surroundings quotes are for the representation of the strings:

```
>>> print str('''mix quotes:"' ''')
mix quotes:"'
>>> print repr('''mix quotes:"' ''')
'mix quotes:"\' '
```

You might want to check the python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) on strings.

Comment: Thanks for such detail answer, also thanks to other people who replied

Answer (score 1):

The representation of a value should be equivalent to the Python code required to generate it. Since the string "But it didn't sing." contains a single quote, using single quotes to delimit it would create invalid code. Therefore double quotes are used instead.

Comment: "using single quotes to delimit it would create invalid code" is a bit misleading. Of course, escaping would be necessary then, and using `"` removes the need for escaping and makes things more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Python has several rules for outputting the `repr` of strings.

Normally, it uses `'` to surround them, except if there are `'`s within it - then it uses `"` for removing the need of quoting.

If a string contains both `'` and '"`characters, it uses`'`s and quotes the`"`.

As there can be several valid and equivalent representations of a string, these rues might change from version to version.

BTW, in the site you linked to the answer is given as well:

> Q: Why does `%r` sometimes print things with single-quotes when I wrote them with double-quotes?
>
> A: Python is going to print the strings in the most efficient way it can, not replicate exactly the way you wrote them. This is perfectly fine since `%r` is used for debugging and inspection, so it's not necessary that it be pretty.