# In Python str.replace treat double and single quote in same manner?

Tags: python

Bear with me I am new to Python. I wrote a simple script to parse a long string which contains multiple substrings wrapped in single quote. I used `str.replace` to replace single quote to empty string. However input string is changed with double quote instead. I ran the script with new input by accident and in my surprise it still replaced all double quote to empty string.

I thought I read in somewhere in Python, double quote and single quote are treated same. Is that correct statement?

Update:

My apology. I must have confused others with this question including myself. I ran quick test script to verify the output what I saw from the original script however I don't see the same output. I tried to replace input string contains double quote (e.g. `str="foo \"abc\" \"efg\""` with `str.replace("'","")` but it didn't do. I had to re-examine the original script and input string it is trying to parse. Thank you for taking your time looking into this thread.

I just verified that part of the original script (rather long and a bit complex one by saying that I didn't tell the whole truth about this script in the context of my question, I am sorry about that) misled me to believe (for a while) Python `str.replace` treat double and single quote in same manner which was wrong assumption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

Comment: I'm not following your description of events. Can you post some code and its output?

Comment: reference pep8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, they are treated the same. But that means, *as far as the language is concerned*, you can use either single or double quotes. However, *they are not the same character*. If you have eg.

```
text = "I said 'hello' to him"
```

the outer, double quotes just delimit the string, while the inner, single quotes are part of the string itself. So, if you run

```
text.replace("'", "")
```

they single quotes will be replaced. But if you do

```
text.replace('"', "")
```

nothing happens, since your string does not contain double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Single- and Double-quotes are treated the same *in your code*. In other words,

```
'Hello' == "Hello"
```

and whether you use `'` or `"` makes no difference.

Say, however, that you have a string that *contains* the characters `'` or `"`:

```
long_string = "So I said 'and what do you mean by that?' and she responded 'I dunno' and ..."
```

This is a string that contains a `'` character. Note that I used `"` as the character to designate this string in the code; therefore, I can use `'` characters inside the string without having to escape them. It works the same the other way around:

```
>>> print( '"' )   # "
>>> print( "'" )   # '
```

If you want a double-quote character inside a double-quoted string, then you have to escape it:

```
>>> print( "\"" )  # "
>>> print( '\'' )  # '
```

Now, back to your question. You had a string like `long_string`, with single-quote characters inside it. To remove them, you can simply do

```
string_without_quotes = long_string.replace( "'", "" ) # or '\''
```