# Syntax Error in if statement with operators

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and was wondering what is wrong with this code:

```
num1 = input("Please Eneter A Number")
num2 = input("Please Enter Another Number")

operation = input("Please Enter An Operation You Want To Do (example: +, -, *, /): ")

if operation == +:
    print(num1 + num2)

if operation == -:
    print(num1 - num2)

if operation == /:
    print(num1 / num2)

if operation == *:
    print(num1 * num2)
```

this is the error I get when trying to run this code:

```
    if operation == +:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I could not find any problem of this sort on this forum.
Please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Comment: you're missing your quotes, e.g. `'+'`

Comment: Also, `input()` returns strings, so num1 and num2 aren't integers, so your math operations won't work.  To convert the input to integer form, use `num1 = int(input('enter a number'))`

Comment: In future, you should work out for yourself which part of the code is relevant to the bug. You can delete almost all of your code and still get the same bug. This process means you're not wasting other people's time and can help you fix it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Python expects to receive strings as stdin input, so try

```
if operation == '+':
```

Also, your `num1`, `num2` are also going to be strings, so you'll need to call

```
num1 = int(num1)
```

or

```
num1 = float(num1)
```

on them to make them integers or floats (and same with `num2`)

Comment: why does it need to be in a stdin (' ') and not in string format (" ")?

Comment: @TakeAByteOutOfTech https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Each of your operators must be in quotes as you are recieving a character input. Besides, you must convert your input numbers to int or float