# Create a graph from data of multiple sheets by Xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I want to overlay multiple sheets of data on a graph with Xlwings.
This is the code I wrote, but of course you get this error.

```py
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
readdata = pd.read_csv('c:Users/user/test.csv')
xw.Range('A1').value = readdata

chart = sht.charts.add()
chart.set_source_data(xw.sheets[0].range('A3:A50, C3:C50'),xw.sheets[1].range('A3:A50, C3:C50'))
```

Error Msg.

> set_source_data() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I want to create a graph like this image with xlwings.

[image]

I'm doing a project that runs macros in Python.
I want to migrate from VBA to Python to simplify macro creation and management.

I'm afraid I can communicate with my ugly English.
Please let me know the solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but as a general debugging tip you could check `xw.sheets[0].range('A3:A50, C3:C50')` and `xw.sheets[1].range('A3:A50, C3:C50')` to see if they are returning what you expect them to be returning.

Comment: What is this notation of single quotes around two ranges separated by a comma, i.e. `'A3:A50, C3:C50'`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Since it is Python code you can use [single quotes as well as double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56190/3219613) and coma seperated addresses in VBA range are handled as you would select both addresses at once. Actually it is a range that consists of 2 [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://%20https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Chart.set_source_data) the

```
xlwings.Chart.set_source_data(source)
```

Sets the source data range for the chart, and accepts one parameter `source` of type `Range` eg:

```
source = xw.books['Book1'].sheets[0].range('A1')
```

---

So try instead

```
chart.set_source_data(xw.sheets[0].range('A3:A50, C3:C50'))
```