# Python console returns single quotes for string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the Python console returns single quotes for string literals for all types of quote delimeters?

```
>> '1'
'1'
>> "1"
'1'
>>"""1"""
'1'
```

Comment: string literals are *source code*, they all produce *string objects*, which have no knowledge of the literal that produced them (why would they?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

Comment: For the same reason that -0 is 0 - `"1"` and `'1'` are the same string, and 0 and -0 are the same number.

Comment: no I'm not asking single vs double quotes, I'm asking why they all return single quotes.

Comment: The string doesn't know or remember how you wrote it in the first place, any more than the number 0 remembers whether you gave it a minus sign. It is just a value.

Comment: @kaya3 although floats have signed 0's

Comment: @Djangonow **because there are no single or double quotes, or triple quotes in the string**. The string objects is defined by the *characters* (rather, unicode code points) it contains. What type of string literal that is used in the source code to create it isn't information that the object has, or should have.

Answer (score 0):

Python makes it convenient for itself to handle objects in [a simple manner](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). If you really need an explicit way of memorizing quotes use literal quote characters.

```py
>>> "\"\"Look, I'm around two qoutes!!!\"\""
'""Look, I\'m around two double qoutes!!!""'
```