# Python Grouping List into Tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm having trouble with my assignment. The requirement is

```
listA = ["a","b","c"]

listB = [1,2,3]

listC = [4,5,6]
```

I need to print out the list of tuples as in the following form:

```
[("a",(1,4)),("b",(2,5)),("c",(3,6))]
```

Here is what I've done:

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = [1,2,3]
c = [4,5,6]
bc = list(zip(b,c))
abc = list(zip(a,bc))
print(abc)
```

The output of my code is:

```
[('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, 6))]
```

I'm not sure that my code is correct because it has a little difference between my output and the requirement's output. My output is 'a', 'b', 'c' instead of "a", "b", "c". Can anyone give me some idea, please?

Comment: Signle quotes (') and double quotes (") are equivalent in Python. So your are fine, those are the same outputs

Comment: @ktv6 thank you so much. I thought single quote (') is for character and double quote (") is for string like C++ so it really made me confusing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After getting the the list, how can I print another list with second value is average of the 2 value in the first list. For example, after getting my list is [('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, 6))], how can I write another function to print [('a',2.5),('b',3.5),('c',4.5)]?

Comment: @JohnyDang, this is a different problem and you should post it as another question or edit it into your original post as the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is correct, " or ' doesn't matter in python. But in Java ' is used for char, and " is used for String. I attached another approach.

```
container = []
for i in range(len(listA)):
         container.append((listA[i],(listB[i],listC[i])))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After getting the container[], how can I print another list with second value is average of the 2 value in the first list. For example, after getting my list is [('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, 6))], how can I write another function to print [('a',2.5),('b',3.5),('c',4.5)]?

Comment: All are the same as up, just change (listB[i],listC[i]) to listB[i]+listC[i]/2

Comment: I meant just base on the final list, which is base on  [('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, 6))]. How can I do it without using the previous problem?

Comment: average = sum(abc[i][1]) / len(abc[i][1])  <- you can use a for loop to access it and take the average, note that i is the index of the container and 1 is the index of the tuple