# win43.client restrict combining many filters

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm trying to read outlook emails via python, have code like below:

```
        import win32com.client
        import os 
        from datetime import datetime, timedelta
        
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mapi = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
        
        messages = mapi.Folders("test@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test").Items
        

       today_change = timedelta(7)
       today = datetime.today()
       start_date = today - today_change
       start_date = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
       today = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
        
        messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start_date
        + "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" + today +  "' And  @SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%deleted%')")
```

I'm trying to add more filters than 1, but I can't manage to do that.
Can someone explain how should I add/merge more filters? Separately they work fine.

Comment: Since I still coudn't manage to get this work in one phrase, I'm just using:

`messages2 = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start_date
+ "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" + today + "'")

messages2 = messages2.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%deleted%')")`

and it do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`@SQL=` prefix can only be used to prefix the whole query. Also, it is better to use `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` instead of `PR_SUBJECT` (the former property is what gets indexed).

Try the following (off the top of my head):

```
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=ReceivedTime >= '" + start_date
        + "' And ReceivedTime <= '" + today +  "' And ""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" LIKE '%deleted%' ")
```

Comment: Hey, this filter doesn't show any message for me (at least no error tho). And I don't really know what's this link in code. I would be grateful if you could explain a bit more.

Comment: It is not a link, it is a DASL property name of the `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT` MAPI property. Try to get rid of the date restriction - do you get back any results?

Comment: Yep, I'm receiving mails with string delete in subject. Still can't find way to get multiple filters at the same time!

Comment: Please the actual value of your restriction string with the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SQL syntax in the following way:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("""@SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" >= '" + start_date
        + "' And "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" <= '" + today +  "' And "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" LIKE '%deleted%')""")
```

See [Filtering Items Using Query Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-query-keywords) for more information.

Comment: Hey, there is an error from this one: <COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Restrict
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occured.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook'

Comment: It seems you need to use `Chr(34)` instead of double quotes in the search string.

Comment: I've updated the search string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping, but still it shows errors. With &: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'", and if I switch to "+" instead of "&", then old one....

Comment: Ohh.. you need to use + in python.

Comment: You may find how to embed double quotes in the [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python) thread.